# Sharing large partition key in Cassandra: how to keep a fixed shard size?

Tags: cassandra, partitioning, sharding

I read [this post](https://foundev.medium.com/synthetic-sharding-in-cassandra-to-deal-with-large-partitions-2124b2fd788b) on how to deal with large partitions and partitioning hotspots, their solution is to add a sharding key as part of the partition key, and **keep the shard size at a fixed size**, say 1000. The fixed shard size even helps pagination.

But my question is, how can we keep a fixed shard size? In my understanding, the common approach for hotspot issue is to add a sharding key (`random_number % n` for example) to the partition key to split hotspots, but it does not guarantee to limit shard size, wondering how it works out in their approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post details a number of approaches to the sharding problem - the first just has a number of shards but no way in which to track how many shard you have stored for a given partition.

The second solution adds a static count column which provides that information but it will fall foul of read-before-write and race conditions on inserting to the shard, especially when data is inserted in parallel. If you get around that however, and you know the size of a row is relatively static, then you can use the counter to control the size (approximately). If the size varies considerably, its a rough guess at best.

The third solution is the same as your %n - in that a fixed number of shards, or 'buckets' are assumed to exist.

I would start the process though by calculating what you expect each partition to contain, and work from there, and not to prematurely optimise.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your detailed answer.  for the first approach, "no way in which to track how many shard you have stored for a given partition.", do you mean no way to accurately or efficiently track how many rows in sharded partition?

Comment: There is no efficient row count mechanism for the partition which you can access without performing a select query against the whole of that partition. Any such value would have to be maintained externally and stored (which is what the static column solution is doing)